# Creating a proxy buffed stdout/stdin in python

Tags: python, subprocess

Currently vim has a bug where sending large string can cause deadlock. https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/2548 Discussion is still on going on how to fix it.

As a workaround I thought of using python as a proxy executable that will auto buffer stdout/stdin/stderr so it will not hang.

If I wanted to start `executable` in vim, I would first start a python script which would look something like `python proxy.py -- executable -arg0 -arg1`. Python would then start the executable with the proper arguments and would buffer the stdout and stdin so vim would only get 1024 bytes at a time and python would only read 1024 bytes at a time.

What would be the best way to accomplish this in python without blocking?

Answer (score 0):

This example works for me:

```
import subprocess
import sys

BUFSIZE = 1024    

p = subprocess.Popen(sys.argv[1:], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, bufsize=BUFSIZE)

while True:
    chunk = sys.stdin.read(BUFSIZE)
    if not chunk:
        break
    p.stdin.write(chunk)
    p.stdin.flush()

p.stdin.close()
p.wait()
```

I tested it with

```
ls -lR | python proxy.py cat -n
```

and

```
echo 123 | python proxy.py cat -n
```